# Writing to gl_FragColor causes glUseProgram to throw GL_INVALID_OPERATION

Tags: opengl-es, glsl, glsles

I'm trying to write a blur filter in GLSL ES 2.0 and I'm getting an Error with the line assigning gl_FragColor. I've not been able to figure out why

```
#extension GL_OES_EGL_image_external : require
precision mediump float;
varying vec2 textureCoordinate;
uniform samplerExternalOES s_texture;
void main() {
  float gaus[25] = float[25](0.01739, 0.03478, 0.04347, 0.03478, 0.01739,
                             0.03478, 0.07282, 0.10434, 0.07282, 0.03478,
                             0.04347, 0.10434, 0.13043, 0.10434, 0.04347,
                             0.03478, 0.07282, 0.10434, 0.07282, 0.03478,
                             0.01739, 0.03478, 0.04347, 0.03478, 0.01739);
  float offset[5] = float[5](-2.0, -1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 2.0);
  vec4 outSum = vec4(0.0);
  int rowi = 0;
  for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    vec4 inSum = vec4(0.0);
    for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++){
      inSum += texture2D(s_texture, textureCoordinate + vec2(offset[i], offset[j]))*gaus[j*5+i];
    }
    outSum += inSum*gaus[rowi+i];
    rowi += 3;
  }
  gl_FragColor = outSum;
}
```

The assignment of `gl_FragColor` causes calls to `glUseProgram` to error with `GL_INVALID_OPERATION`. I've tried this without it and it compiles and operates without the error.  I'm hoping someone can point me in a direction i haven't looked yet at least because I can't see any reason this isn't working.

EDIT: I solved this. As best I can tell the GLSL-ES on android doesn't allow indexing arrays with non-constant variables. GLSE-ES 2.0 specification page 97 10.25 states it's not directly supported by all implementations and on page 109 it states that loop indices can be considered constant-expressions but not must. I rolled out my loop and it's linking fine now.

Thank you everyone who responded, I was able to narrow this down thanks to your insight.

Comment: Are you sure you are compiling this as a fragment shader, not a vertex shader?

Comment: `*the assignment of gl_FragColor causes GL_INVALID_OPERATION*` No it does not. Nothing in a shader can "cause GL_INVALID_OPERATION" because GL_INVALID_OPERATION is a runtime *OpenGL Error*. Only OpenGL functions cause these. Now, writing to that variable may cause the shader to *fail to compile or link*, and if you don't notice that, you'll eventually get a `GL_INVALID_OPERATION` error when you *render*. But it is always the *rendering* that causes the error (specifically rendering with a bad program), not the shader itself. So, are you getting any shader compile/linking errors?

Comment: There are no other errors that I'm getting, and yes it is being compiled as a fragment shader. And I've no idea why i'm getting GL_INVALID_OPERATION because when i remove the one line "gl_FragColor = outSum;" it doesn't happen. The error is being thrown on glUseProgram if that helps any but I can't see any reason why

Comment: if i add "gl_FragColor = texture2D(s_texture, textureCoordinate)" at the end it will compile and run but then it's not doing what i'm trying to do, however no errors then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What happens if you remove these lines?

```
uniform float gaus[25];
uniform float offset[5];
```

gaus and offset are not uniforms. They are assigned constant values inside main(). And I don't think you should declare variables with the same names as uniforms.

I remember reading that when a shader is compiled, the compiler is really good at stripping unnecessary code from the shader. When you leave out the line

```
gl_FragColor = outSum;
```

or assign

```
texture2D(s_texture, textureCoordinate)
```

to gl_FragColor, gaus and offset are not used to calculate the final value of gl_FragColor, so it is possible that they are being stripped out and the variable naming collisions don't occur. When you assign outSum to gl_FragColor, gaus and offset are used to calculate outSum, so they are not stripped and naming collisions occur, causing errors.

Comment: Yes I've actually removed those lines since i posted this, the effect was the same

Answer (score 2):

`glUseProgram` can only throw `GL_INVALID_OPERATION` if:

1. the program is not a valid program object.
2. the program's last link operation was not successful.

Obviously your writing to this variable caused a shader compilation or linking error which you did not detect. So start catching your compiler/linker errors instead of ignoring them.

Comment: I'm writing this for android and admittedly very new to OpenGL and GLSL, this all is a learning experiment for me. So I don't know(and haven't found) how to do that.  I am currently output the infolog for the fragshader and program and nothing showing up there.

Comment: @shbi: If you're learning, why are you dealing with textures before you've got a handle on making program objects? You should start with decent program and shader compiling code that [detects errors](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenGL_Programming/Modern_OpenGL_Introduction#Vertex_shader).

Comment: Unfortunately for a few reasons, I need to use textures for my senior project and because I haven't found many useful sources that actually cover error handling. So my impression was that I understood this.

Answer (score 0):

This is more of an extension to Nicol's answer.

I ran into the same issue and turns out that the link for the program failed. Unfortunately `glGetError` after `glLinkProgram` does not return an error, and I did not end up catching it. I added the following that helped me log errors after the link, and has been very useful.

```
GLint logLength;
glGetProgramiv( program_id, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &logLength );
if ( logLength > 0 )
{
    char* log = new char[ logLength + 1 ];
    log[ logLength ] = '\0';
    glGetProgramInfoLog( program_id, logLength, &logLength, log );
    Dbg_Printf( "OpenGL Program Link Log:\n%s\n", log );
    delete[] log;
}
```

BTW, in my case I was exceeding the number of supported attributes in the vertex shader.