# glSecondaryColorPointerEXT replacement using Qt5 OpenGL 3.3

Tags: c++, opengl, qt5

I'm learning OpenGL with Qt5 rewriting some legacy code. They use glSecondaryColorPointerEXT(). After checking the current support for OpenGL in commonly available video cards I've selected Qt5's class [QOpenGLFunctions_3_2_Core](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtgui/qopenglfunctions-3-2-core.html) to access the OpenGL functions.

Is there an OpenGL 3.2 version or replacement method for this function?

Answer (score 2):

In OpenGL 3.2 you should be using shaders, furthermore by this point you should avoid legacy features like `gl_SecondaryColor`. The appropriate replacement for secondary color in a shader-based engine is simply an additional generic vertex attribute. I explained a [very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19077295/writing-to-gl-fragcolor-causes-invalid-operation-on-android/19083064#19083064) related to OpenGL ES 2.0, my answer there may be of some help.

In short, `glVertexPointer (...)`, `glColorPointer (...)`, `glSecondaryColorPointer{EXT} (...)` are all deprecated in OpenGL 3.0. In a 3.2 core context, you cannot use them at all. Thus, you need to learn shaders and [`glVertexAttribPointer (...)`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man3/xhtml/glVertexAttribPointer.xml).

A vertex shader that uses "primary" and "secondary" vertex colors in core GL 3.2 would look something like this:

```
#version 150 core

uniform mat4 mvp;

in      vec4 vtx_pos;
in      vec4 vtx_color1;
in      vec4 vtx_color2;

out     vec4 color;

void main (void) {
  gl_Position = mvp * vtx_pos;
  color       = vtx_color1 * vtx_color2; // It is up to you to decide what to do
                                         //   with the primary and secondary
                                         //     colors, this is just for show...
}
```

You would supply data to vtx_pos, vtx_color1 and vtx_color2 by using `glVertexAttribPointer (...)` using the attribute location queried from the GLSL vertex shader (after linking). And all this completely does away with the need for a `glSecondaryColorPointerEXT (...)`.

Comment: Which means that instead of translating the legacy code and fixing a few legacy functions I have to rewrite the entire thing. I chose 3.2 core because most video cards support it but not version 4. Not a thrilling answer :(

Comment: @Jay: Do not use 3.2 core then :) You can access most 3.2 features from a 3.2 compatibility profile, and in fact you do not need to use shaders if you do this. It is definitely not the best way of approaching modern OpenGL, but if you're dealing with a legacy codebase this may be your only transitional option. That is what the compatibility profile is designed for, easing the upgrade process.

Comment: @Jay: I am no expert in Qt, but it only took me a couple of seconds to locate [`QOpenGLFunctions_3_2_Compatibility`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtgui/qopenglfunctions-3-2-compatibility.html) in the SDK documentation. This is without a doubt what you will want to use. If you use this, then you have access to `glSecondaryColorPointer (...)` without the EXT suffix, since it is part of OpenGL 3.2 compatibility, no extension needed.

Comment: @Jay: All the assumes of course you are not targeting OS X 10.7+. The only way to get 3.2 functionality on this platform is to use a core profile context (it does not allow 3.2 compatibility). In which case, you would be better off sticking with OpenGL 2.1.

Comment: @Jay: I'd like to throw in that by transitioning legacy code to modern OpenGL you'll very likely reduce your OpenGL related codebase by a sizeable fraction. It might sound counterintuitive (you've to write shaders now, load them, and so on), but the savings in LoC simply by writing down in a shader what you want, rather than throwing a gazillion of state switches pays off. The only speedbump in transistioning are Display Lists; if your program uses those you'll be in for a lot of rewriting.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman Thanks for the help. I chose core because I understood OSX didn't implement compatibility. I'll try a 2.1 version and see if things might work better there. I really appreciate the advice. When you're a noob you can easily go astray

Comment: @datenwolf I considered that. The legacy code is the render system plugin for Ogre3d. The interface between the engine and the render system defines what functionality I need to implement. I can't really change things much without rewriting the engine as well.