# Why gl_Color is not a built-in variable for the fragment shader?

Tags: opengl

The vertex shader is expected to output vertices positions in clip space:

> Vertex shaders, as the name implies, operate on vertices.
>   Specifically, each invocation of a vertex shader operates on a single
>   vertex. These shaders must output, among any other user-defined
>   outputs, a clip-space position for that vertex. (source: [Learning Modern 3D Graphics Programming, by Jason L. McKesson](http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut/Basics/Tut01%20Following%20the%20Data.html))

It has a built-in variable named `gl_Position` for that.

Similarly, the fragment shader is expected to output colors:

> A fragment shader is used to compute the output color(s) of a
>   fragment. [...] After the fragment shader executes, the fragment
>   output color is written to the output image.  (source: [Learning
>   Modern 3D Graphics Programming, by Jason L. McKesson](http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut/Basics/Tut01%20Following%20the%20Data.html))

but there is no `gl_Color` built-in variable defined for that as stated here: [opengl44-quick-reference-card.pdf](http://www.khronos.org/files/opengl44-quick-reference-card.pdf)

**Why that (apparent) inconsistency in the OpenGL API?**

Comment: Because the clip-space position is something special, it has to treated in a very special way inside of the pipeline, in contrast to any other user-defined vertex outputs. But a value put out from the fragment shader is not different from any other value put out from it. What is special are the depth and stencil values put out from the fragment shader (if any) and for those there is a special output variable.

Comment: ... because a shader *can* output several values (with Multiple Render Targets or such). So there is no single "gl_Color" value. Just user-defined outputs. See glDrawBuffers and its GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENTn parameter.

Comment: That tutorial no longer works and the author, who used to be a regular on Stack Overflow, Nicol Bolas has not been seen in two years. I really hope he is doing alright.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because the OpenGL pipeline uses `gl_Position` for several tasks. [The manual says](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/manglsl/xhtml/gl_Position.xml): "The value written to gl_Position will be used by primitive assembly, clipping, culling and other fixed functionality operations, if present, that operate on primitives after vertex processing has occurred."

In contrast, the pipeline logic does not depend on the final pixel color.

Comment: So this is a design choice to force the user to set gl_Position because the pipeline needs it, while color is actually not required? Any historical reasons or technical reasons?

Comment: According to [this](http://www.glprogramming.com/red/chapter05.html), you don't have to set a value. It will just have a default value of 0.  However, I think that that could be outdated. Easiest way to find out: Try it!

Comment: Well, for both vertex and fragment shader, I do not HAVE to output a value. Well, I got nothing but it compiles and run fine;) Thanks for your answers.

Comment: If you feel that I left something unanswered, feel free to ask me in private or modify your question.

Comment: Thanks. It was mainly a API design question and I understood the thinking behind this apparent inconsistency;)

Comment: @Korchkidu: Actually if you do not output anything in a fragment shader, you implicitly output depth whether you realize it or not. You can specify your own depth by writing to `gl_FragDepth` or have GLSL automatically assign `gl_FragDepth` the value that was generated during rasterization. Color does not work this way, however, just depth.

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer does not adequately explain the real situation:

`gl_Color` **was** *already* used once-upon-a-time, but it was always defined as an **input** value.

In compatibility GLSL, `gl_Color` is the color vertex pointer in vertex shaders and it takes on the value of `gl_FrontColor` or `gl_BackColor` depending on which side of the polygon you are shading in a fragment shader.

However, none of this behavior exists in newer versions of GLSL. You must supply your own vertex attributes, your own varyings and you pick between colors using the value of `gl_FrontFacing`. I actually [explained this in more detail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19077295/writing-to-gl-fragcolor-causes-invalid-operation-on-android/19083064#19083064) in a different question related to OpenGL ES 2.0, but the basic principle is the same.

In fact, since `gl_Color` was already used as an input variable this is why the output of a fragment shader is called `gl_FragColor` instead. You cannot have a variable serve both as an input and an output in the same stage. The existence of an `inout` storage qualifier may lead you to believe otherwise, but *that is for function parameters only*.