# Is there a reliable alternative to gl_FrontFacing in a fragment shader?

Tags: opengl, glsl, fragment-shader

In my past experience, support for `gl_FrontFacing` has been spotty.  Sometimes it just fails, and sometimes it causes a fallback to software rendering.  So I tried using `GL_VERTEX_PROGRAM_TWO_SIDE`, setting different front and back secondary colors, and testing the secondary color.  But I found that on at least one ATI card, that approach caused intermittent failure to compile shaders.  So, can anyone think of any other technique to tell whether a fragment is facing forward?

By the way, some folks don't seem to believe that `gl_FrontFacing` could ever fail, so I did some searching on the opengl.org forums and Apple's OpenGL mailing list.  I found a dozen or so mentions of `gl_FrontFacing` failing, in one way or another, on various cards, some from ATI and some from NVidia.  Most of these mentions are from 2009 or earlier.  So if I could assume that all my users have machines made in the last 5 years, I'd probably be OK.  But I don't think I can assume that.

Comment: You mean `gl_FrontFacing`, right? I've never seen `gl_FrontFace`. What platforms did you have problems on?

Comment: @RetoKoradi:  Thanks for the spelling correction.  The issue with two-sided coloring was on Windows, and I think the `gl_FrontFacing` issue may have been on Mac.

Comment: How can support for that be spotty? The rasterizer absolutely has to know whether it is filling a front- or back-facing polygon, all it has to do is pass this state onto the fragment shader. Maybe you just are not dealing with `bool` data types correctly in your shader? However, primary and secondary colors are deprecated - support for that can definitely be spotty. Consider interpolating your own output variables instead.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman, what do you mean by "interpolating your own output variables"?  What interpolated value would tell me whether the fragment is front-facing?

Comment: None, `gl_FrontFacing` tells you that. But instead of using `gl_FrontColor` or `gl_BackColor` use a custom output. This is actually all explained in another answer I wrote [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19077295/writing-to-gl-fragcolor-causes-invalid-operation-on-android/19083064#19083064). There is even a fragment shader that does exactly what you want at the very end of that answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since the position in view space is also the direction away from the camera, following expression seems to be quite good approximation of gl_FrontFacing:

```
dot (normal, position) < 0.0
```

This would still give you minor artifacts around the edges, but less severe than in @datenwolf solution. See [my blog post](https://makc3d.wordpress.com/2015/09/17/alternative-to-gl_frontfacing/) for detailed discussion :)

**Update**: if you're willing to use WebGL extensions, even better test is possible. There you can calculate face normal estimation, that works on both front and back side, therefore, testing its dot product with our vertex normal results in this probably pixel-perfect shader:

```
#extension GL_OES_standard_derivatives : enable
vec3 fdx = dFdx(position);
vec3 fdy = dFdy(position);
vec3 faceNormal = normalize(cross(fdx,fdy));
if (dot (normal, faceNormal) > 0.0) {
    // gl_FrontFacing is almost certainly true
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you're saying it's a WebGL extension; the derivative functions have been part of the OpenGL Shading Language since version 1.10.  But anyway, that's basically what I ended up doing.

Comment: coming from webgl background here. completely missed the question was about opengl.

Answer (score 2):

Pass the transformed face normal (interpolated vertex normal) to the fragment shader and test the sign of the z component. Yes I know it's not really the same thing as a winding based front/back face test, but close enough.

Comment: It's not close enough for my purposes.  I tried that, and got unpleasant artifacts around the edges, from triangles that are nearly edge-on to the camera.